# On a sequence with $n^{\frac{1}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}}$ unbounded, where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the product of primes dividing $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, experimental-mathematics

One knows the easy

> **Fact.** $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$$

My proof is defining $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}$ then take logarithms to show that $\log l=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}=0$, and thus exponentiation yields previous **Fact.**

Let the [radical of an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) defined as you see in previous *Wikipedia* by $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$, and when $n>1$ then $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{p\mid n}p,$$
that is **the product of all distinct primes dividing** $n$ (examples are $\operatorname{rad}(29)=29$ and $\operatorname{rad}(28)=\operatorname{rad}(4\cdot 7)=2\cdot 7 $ since this arithmetic function is **multiplicative**).

Inspired in different calculations and experiments, I've considered the following

> **Question.** Can you provide us **a characterization of a sequence of positive integers with** $$n^{\frac{1}{\operatorname{rad}(n)}}$$
>   **unbounded**? It is: is it possible a (an infinite) sequence  $n_k$ of positive integers such that  $$n_k^{\frac{1}{\operatorname{rad}(n_k)}}$$ tends to infinite?

**Many thanks.** I was interested in this question after experiments also with different arithmetic functions, I say divisors functions.

Comment: what do you get with the logarithm

Comment: The problems is that with my computer I see a possible counterexample. I say that if my calculations with my computer are rights seems that there is a sequence with values relatively larges. Thanks @user1952009 In any case, you can show that always is 0?

Comment: come on... did you try anything before asking this question ? in particular $rad(n^k) = rad(n), \ln n^k = k \ln n$, so $\frac{\ln n^k}{rad(n^k)} > c \implies k > \ldots$

Comment: I am sorry user, you are right.  I am alone here, and boring myself. Best is think good mathematics. Thanks @user1952009

Comment: read a book, for example [apostol's elementary number theory](https://www.google.fr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=apostol%20elementary%20number%20theory)

Comment: Thanks user, you are the best professor to me, you and the other users @user1952009

Comment: @user1952009 then you are saying that it is deduced from the existence of integer $n^k$ with  $k>c\frac{rad(n)}{\log (n)}$? It is a difficult reasoning currently to me, I say that I have no such ideas. Very thanks much,

Comment: it is obvious that with $f(n) = \frac{\ln n}{rad(n)}$ you have $f(n^k) = k f(n)$, isn't it ?

Comment: @user1952009 now if I do a comparison between my question and your answer in comments, it is obvious, but, to me, not before. Your answer, and **barto's** answer, from my viewpoint was necessary a beautiful idea, or perhaps a good background from which one gets quickly examples/counterexamples reasonings and simple proofs. Very thanks much for your attention. Now I understand much more this exercise.

Comment: you know how important are the square-free numbers ($\mu_n = \pm 1$), they are precisely those for which $rad(n) = n$, and the more $n$ as some high powers in its factors, the more $rad(n) < n$

Comment: Many thanks @RobertZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is $n_k=2^k$: $n_k^{\frac1{rad(n_k)}}=\sqrt2^k\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty$.

In general, a necessary condition is that the maximal exponent of a prime in the factorisation of $n_k$ is unbounded, because if $n_k=p_1^{a_1}\cdots$ with $a_1$ maximal (say), $n_k^{\frac1{rad(n_k)}}\leq rad(n_k)^{\frac{a_1}{rad(n_k)}}\leq\sqrt2^{a_1}$.

However this is not sufficient, e.g. $n_k=2^k\cdot p_2\cdots p_{k+1}$ has $n_k^{\frac1{rad(n_k)}}$ bounded.

Comment: Right then $2^{k/2}$ is such unbounded sequence. Very thanks much

Comment: Feel free if you want improve the answer, I accept your nice anwer now, since you was very quick. Very thanks much.